# How to get flexbox to fill horizontal AND vertical space?

Tags: flexbox

I have this HTML using the new flexbox:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0
        }

        div#outer-container {
            height: 100%;
        }

        div#inner-container {
            display: flex;
            height: 100%;
            flex-direction: row;
        }

        div #left {flex: 1; background-color: yellow;}
        div #center {flex: 5; background-color: #fdd;}
        div #right {flex: 1; background-color: pink;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="outer-container">
        <div>HEADER</div>
        <div id="inner-container">
            <div id="left"></div>
            <div id="center"></div>
            <div id="right"></div>
        </div>
        <div>FOOTER</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It expands horizontally fine, but vertically it goes over 100% height because of the header/footer DIVs. How would you get that not to happen?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out - set the height to 80% and make the header/footer height 5%.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could set the outer-container to display: flex, and get a vertical flexbox container with a horizontal flex box container inside. Then your footer and header can grow and shrink more dynamically than with a fixed height.

Tested in Chrome.

```
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0
        }

        div#outer-container {
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: ;
        }

        div#inner-container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;

            flex-grow: 2;
        }

        div #left {flex: 1; background-color: yellow;}
        div #center {flex: 5; background-color: #fdd;}
        div #right {flex: 1; background-color: pink;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="outer-container">
        <div>HEADER</div>
        <div id="inner-container">
            <div id="left">tet</div>
            <div id="center">tet</div>
            <div id="right">test</div>
        </div>
        <div>FOOTEfeawR</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```